# Sporadically slow WiFi connection on MacBook

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

Sporadically, but frequently, the WiFi connection on my MacBook gets exceedingly slow. I'll be browsing around with no problem one minute, and then the next, everything will slow to a crawl. I can't figure out any rhyme or reason to it. It *seems* to fix itself if I turn WiFi off and back on again, but that could just be my imagination...and even if so, it doesn't last.

Two things that make this weirder: one, my iPhone will continue working fine when the MacBook's WiFi craps out, even if they're right next to each other (so that would seem to rule out interference). Two, the WiFi on the MacBook never *drops* - it just gets very slow. Yet, while it's doing this, the WiFi status icon will show full strength, and Network Diagnostics will report that everything is normal.

Any ideas or anything I can try, please let me know!

Comment: did you update the OS on your macbook recently?   I did the update and now my wifi speed is crawling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the cause of this was...the baby monitor! If the monitor is on and close to the MacBook, it apparently interferes with the wifi. If I simply move it far enough away, that seems to resolve the interference.